Block specific regex in htaccess
There is a way to block all the requests with a certain querystring?
GET /?7eyS=cUYD HTTP/2
GET /?8dkG=TMWZ HTTP/2
GET /?viYF=4KbU HTTP/2
GET /?Wv3y=oCSA HTTP/2


Please tell us exactly what pattern you want to block in query string and what you have tried as code yourself.

use this code
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*=.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*\?.*$
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]

or
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}=[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}$"
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>


This is simply:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)7eyS= [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)8dkG= [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)viYF= [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)Wv3y= [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ - [F]
</IfModule>

Or am I missing something?

Since the request pattern appears to be auto generated one probably can simplify the matching pattern to RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)[\d\w]{4}=, matching all such parameters with a key having 4 characters made up of digits and small case letters.
